# Block IP address from text filename in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block an IP address if a filename inside a folder matches the IP address.

E.g., Inside `somefolder/firewall/` is a text file with filename `x.x.x.x.txt`
(x is replaced with the actual IP).

.htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond somefolder/firewall/%{REMOTE_ADDR}.txt -f
RewriteRule . - [F]
```

Any ideas what's wrong with the code?

**Update:**
I got it to work by using absolute path

E.g.,
`RewriteCond /home/user/somefolder/firewall/%{REMOTE_ADDR}.txt -f`

Question now is, are there ways to use relative path instead?

Comment: Not sure about the issue itself, looks correct at a glance; but what "scale" are you planning to use this on? I think using `DENY FROM ip1 ip2 ...` might be the preferable solution - checking against file names might require too many file system read operations?

Comment: @CBroe I need to be able to add IPs when a trigger is made from a PHP app. Then delete IP entries that are beyond x days. I don't I think can do that with `deny`. I was inpired by this https://serverfault.com/a/834833/75899

Comment: I would rather keep the necessary info in a database or PHP array then, and re-create the .htaccess file dynamically when necessary ...

Comment: @CBroe That is one way but that's a lot of "steps" so it's possibly slower. Also, the htaccess file contains a lot of other directives so dynamically editing is a bit messy in my use case.

Comment: _"so it's possibly slower"_ - than having to perform a file system look-up for each and every single IP address that might request something from your site? Not even sure if error handling/logging for "invalid" file system characters like the `:` ever so present in IPv6 addresses might not cause an additional performance "penalty". Plus, DENY gives you the ability to work with partial addresses, whereas if I attacked your site from a whole IP block under my control, you'd have to create a file for every single one ...

Comment: @CBroe I'm under the impression that loading a single file is faster vs loading a file then searching if an IP exist on that file.  That's 1 vs 2 steps already. And "by slower" I mean DB queries + recreating htaccess every time. But anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? Adding/removing IP addresses from this list is an administrative task to be performed every so often, whereas _checking_ for what to block has to happen on every single request ...

Comment: _"Question now is, are there ways to use relative path instead?"_ - you can use the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` variable as a more "dynamic" prefix, if you like. But I still think you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @CBroe My app needs to block/unblock the IP in real time so I'm using my preferred method. I totally understand what you mean and I actually use your `deny` method for "traditional" IP blocking but I deduce that my preffered method is better for my current use case. I'm giving legit users the ability to unblock themselves, doing that in `deny` method is more work whereas here I simply delete the filename with the IP add. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` works, if you want to put that as an answer i'll accept it.